# Azure storage account container name format is incorrect

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake

I'm trying to read a json file from storage account from a container name, the container name is (relative path )

```
var-storage/business/web/
```

file  name is :

```
test.json
```

when I try my code :

```
blobService.getBlobToText(container, blobname, function(error, text){

if(error){

    console.error(error);

    res.status(500).send('Fail to download blob');

} else {

   var data = JSON.parse(text);

   res.status(200).send('Filtered Data you want to send back');

}

});
```

it gives me this error :

```
container name format is incorrect
```

can you help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this issue, please change your container name variable to `var-storage` and your blob name variable to `business/web/test.json` and you should not get the error.

To elaborate more, in Azure Blob Storage the folders are virtual and are essentially part of the blob's name.